# How do I close the current document in GNOME Text Editor?

Tags: gnome-text-editor

When I open GNOME Text Editor (not gedit), by default it opens the last document that I had edited. How do I close this current document so that I get a blank new file that hasn't been saved yet?

Comment: If you don't want GNOME Text Editor to always open the last edited document when launched, you can disable the "Restore Session" option in the preferences. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M1BL.png)

Comment: CTRL+W (as in Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @muru the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+w` will close the current tab (as in Firefox and Chrome). If there is only one document open, the main application window will still remain afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

First, click on the "+" button to open a new document:

[image: Screenshot]

Then click "x" on the tab that you wish to close:

[image: Screenshot]

Now you have a blank document that has not been saved yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you press Ctrl-W with only that restored tab? Does it close the whole window?

Comment: @muru It closes just the tab without closing the whole window! Amazing! I'll accept that as an answer, if you want.

Comment: Nah, you can update your answer with it. It was just a guess and I don't have it handy to test myself.

Comment: Did you try disabling the "Restore Session" option?